# directive scope not binding with $resource

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm experiencing a very strange issue and cannot see what I'mn doing wrong...

I have a pretty simple directive:

```
var widgets = angular.module('widgets', []);
widgets.directive('wdgtImageThumbnail', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/utilities/widgets/wdgtImageThumbnailPrtl.html',
        scope: {
            item: '=',
            imageSettings: '=',
            gotoItem: '&',
            showName: '='
        }, controller: function ($scope) {
            // get basePath and placeholderImage from plsConfig via controller
            // and configure item.image property as required
            var imageBasePath = $scope.imageSettings.imageBasePath;
            var placeholderImage = $scope.imageSettings.placeholderImage;
            $scope.thumbnailImage = imageBasePath + ($scope.item.image || placeholderImage);
        }
    };
});
```

Here is the markup partial for the directive:

```
<div data-ng-click="gotoItem()">
    <div title="Click to view {{item.name}}'s details">
        <h4 class="logo-label" data-ng-show="showName">{{item.name}}</h4>
        <img data-ng-src="{{thumbnailImage}}" class="img-thumbnail logo-pic"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I'm on the URL and refresh my browser, the directive works as required and displays `item.image`.

However, if I navigate away from the page to a list of "items" and then navigate back to an "item", `{{item.image}}` is not binding in the markup.

I have checked using Batarang and, in both cases "item" is on the directive's scope.

So for some reason, in the second scenario, the binding is not occurring. Why would this happen?

---

EDIT:

I'm having trouble simulating this issue in Plunker, because the issue is related to the way calls are made to our api, which isn't public yet.

However, we have established that the issue we're facing has something to do with Angular resourcesw. For some reason, when we refresh the browser, the directive's controller knows what `$scope.item` is, but when we navigate away from the page and then back again, `$scope.item` is undefined. In our test to date, we're using $resource.

This is the controller function calling our datacontext service:

```
function getSubscriber() {
        vm.subscriber = subscriberCtx.getSubscriberById($routeParams.subscriberId);
    }
```

and this is the function in the datacontext:

```
function getSubscriberById(id) {
        return $resource('/api/v1/Subscribers/:id').
            get({id:id});
    }
```

`vm.subscriber` is the object being passed into the directive as the `item` attribute.

What i'm finding really strange is that if I log `$scope.item` form the directive in both the passing and failing cases, the object is logged and in each case the logs are identical.

So, why can the directive not see `$scope.item` in cases when the browser is not refreshed?

If I pass a simple json object in, the directive works perfectly, but we're struggling to ge3t it working with both $resource and restangular.

Comment: Did you try linking function instead of controller?

Comment: @dfsq yes, no difference....

Comment: could you set up a plnkr with the code ?

Comment: @angel edit added with plunker

Comment: @boomba Your plunker is broken      :o

Comment: @ilan figured it might have been but had to run. I'll look tomorrow and edit.